# Eddystone beacons are not working when use Beacons-Android library

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, eddystone

I tried to Implements an Eddystone beacon on android device using beacon-android library `https://github.com/adriancretu/beacons-android#features` as follows.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EddystoneURL beacon = new EddystoneURL("www.github.com");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Beacons.initialize(this);

        beacon.init(5, AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY,AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH,0,"Eddie");
        beacon.start();

        UUID uuid = beacon.getUUID();
        String name = beacon.getName();
        Log.i("Log","name is "+name);
        Log.i("Log",uuid.toString());
        String url = beacon.getURL();
        Log.i("Log",url);
        Log.i("Log","App started");
        int k = beacon.getActiveState();
        Log.i("Log","active state : "+k);
        int powerlvl = beacon.getTxPowerLevel();
        Log.i("Log","Power Lvl : "+ powerlvl);
    }


}
```

and I get logs as follows

```
2020-04-09 20:27:42.771 14922-14922/? I/Log: name is Eddie
2020-04-09 20:27:42.772 14922-14922/? I/Log: 21ac707d-2ef0-4578-aa52-f8b8020d97c3
2020-04-09 20:27:42.772 14922-14922/? I/Log: www.github.com
2020-04-09 20:27:42.772 14922-14922/? I/Log: App started
2020-04-09 20:27:42.772 14922-14922/? I/Log: active state : 0
2020-04-09 20:27:42.772 14922-14922/? I/Log: Power Lvl : 3
```

the problem is the emulated beacon is was not identified by beacon scanners. I really appreciate the help of yours. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this question is about building a transmitter with the beacons-android library, so a better answer would be to show how to make this work properly with that library.

However, if no solution is found and the OP is open to using the [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) (similarly named but completely different) to accomplish this, the code below will do it:

```
try {
    byte[] urlBytes = UrlBeaconUrlCompressor.compress("https://www.github.com"");
    Identifier encodedUrlIdentifier = Identifier.fromBytes(urlBytes, 0, urlBytes.length, false);
    ArrayList<Identifier> identifiers = new ArrayList<Identifier>();
    identifiers.add(encodedUrlIdentifier);
    beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
            .setIdentifiers(identifiers)
            .setTxPower(-59)
            .build();
    BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
            .setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_URL_LAYOUT);
    BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), 
              beaconParser);
    beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "That URL cannot be parsed");
}
```

Full Disclosure:  I am the lead developer on the Android Beacon Library open source project.